# Shared methods in ASP.NET sessions

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multithreading, concurrency, shared

As a followup to the previous question I have asked ["ASP.Net Architecture Specific to Shared/Static functions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742196/asp-net-architecture-specific-to-shared-static-functions)

I am still struggling to understand the implications of using shared methods in ASP.NET.

So for example let us take the following code.

```
    Public Shared Function GetCategoryByID(ByVal CategoryID As Guid) As Category
        If Not CategoryID.Equals(Guid.Empty) Then
            Dim res As New Category

            Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ConnectionString)
                sqlConn.Open()

                Using dr As IDataReader = CategoryDataLayer.GetCategoryByIDQuery(sqlConn, CategoryID)
                    Return CType(BaseDataLayer.FillObject(res, dr), Category)
                End Using
            End Using

        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function
```

Now I imagine client 1 connecting and running this method GetCategoryByID() from their session with the guid {A20E625F-2333-4742-BFD9-05BE7649222D}.

Let us now say that for example the process is about to execute the following line.

```
Using dr As IDataReader = CategoryDataLayer.GetCategoryByIDQuery(sqlConn, CategoryID)
```

At this point client 2 runs the same shared method but with the guid {6D806B82-FC7F-4124-AFB9-45E2689BC9F5}.

Does CategoryID not at this point become {6D806B82-FC7F-4124-AFB9-45E2689BC9F5} and therefor interfere with client 1 because now CategoryID has changed given that this is a shared method?

Could someone please clarify?

PS: I do apologize for what is essentially a duplicate post but in retrospect I don't feel the answer in the original post was clear enough (at least for me). Perhaps I wasn't specific enough either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code sample, the variable `res` is a local variable of the shared method. No one, not even another shared method can touch that variable. It will exist for the lifetime of the method and then its gone. `CategoryId` is the exact same, its a local variable that cannot be touched from outside.

VB has another concept called `Static` which is very different than the C# version of static which can cause some confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The only issue with `Shared` methods is shared *state*.

If you use a `Shared` field or `Static` variable, it will be shared across requests, and cause trouble.

However, a `Shared` method that doesn't use any external state or shared objects will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the same method is being run, it is being run in two different contexts. Any variables local to that method (including the CategoryId parameter) are not shared.